# .htaccess rules to separate page types

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some problems rewriting URLs with the following rules

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?pag=cms&title=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1 [NC,L]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to check if the URL is a cms page or not and leave admin URLs as they are.
If I remove the last condition it works but I will have no rule for not cms pages.

Ideally I would want to have just one rule for every page (cms or not) but I can't figure out how to check that other than using `page/` in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod_rewrite will keep looping through all the rules until the URI stops changing (or it reaches its internal redirect limit, resuling in a 500 error). You need to add a few conditions to the last rule so that it won't rewrite URI's that's already been properly routed:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?pag=cms&title=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1 [NC,L]
```

Additionally, the second rule does nothing except a passthrough, so you can replace it with

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ - [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
'-d' (is directory)
Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
'-f' (is regular file)
Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.
```